# iOS UnitTest the macro definition be nil when I run test

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, macros

when i run single unitTest class it's be ok
when i run all the test class it's be nil
I don't know why the macro definition return nil ? need your help thanks.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vo5Iz.png

Comment: Edit your post instead of adding the screenshot in comment